# How do I output a string instead of a HTML page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, vb.net

I want to be able to output a simple string as text rather than the HTML page when a set of criteria are met. I am currently using:

```
Protected Sub OutputString(ByVal Str As String)
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Str)
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

This works great and does exactly what I want, however, the Response.End() generates exceptions and (I believe) should be avoided where possible.

I suppose I could use a separate "empty" page for this code but its more of a work around than a solution. Also, someone said something about over riding the HTML output behaviour (can't remember where now).

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me the best method.

**UPDATE:**
I found this link :
[Response.Redirect(url) ThreadAbortException Solution](http://web.archive.org/web/20101224113858/http://www.c6software.com/codesolutions/dotnet/threadabortexception.aspx)

It recommends using HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() and over riding the functions that render the page:

```
Dim DoNotOutputHTML As Boolean = False

Protected Overrides Sub RaisePostBackEvent(sourceControl As IPostBackEventHandler, eventArgument As String)
    If DoNotOutputHTML = False Then
        MyBase.RaisePostBackEvent(sourceControl, eventArgument)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    If DoNotOutputHTML = False Then
        MyBase.Render(writer)
    End If
End Sub
```

You can then choose whether or not to output your html page by setting the variable DoNotOutputHTML.

The only problem I have with this is that any code after the CompleteRequest() still executes. I can work around this by restructuring my code although it would be neater (less if/else blocks) if I didn't have to, like I don't with response.end()

Any suggestions?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but I think you can just use `Response.Write` instead of writing the bytes directly.

Comment: What exceptions do you get with `Response.End()
`?

Comment: @minitech Quite right. How dumb am I? lol. Don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I believe the exception is well documented (also affects server.transfer and response.redirect as they use response.end). The exact error I get is:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just used Response.End() and ignored the exceptions. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to set the response type to text, and remove all HTML from the page.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did say that was an option in my question, however, that would mean the page lifecycle would still be processed (even though it is blank) which would not be as efficient as it could be. I would also like to stop any code after the output not to be executed, just how response.end() is doing at the moment.